# Automatically repeating querying stock after failing in python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am fetching a list of 250 stocks in python (from yahoo finance):

shares = ['STOCK1', 'STOCK2', 'STOCK3', 'STOCK4']

for share in shares:
    startd = '2000-01-01'
    endd = '2018-12-31'

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(share, start=startd, end=endd)
```

Let's assume that the code fails to download STOCK3. Is there any command that re-launches the program just for STOCK3 and keeps on repeating it until it succeeds (and then move on to STOCK4)?

Answer (score 0):

1) You might want to try using the [`retrying`](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/) library and try a few times within the given run.

2) You might want to add the stocks to a job queue, have something consume from the queue, and upon failure add it back to the queue. There are various sorts of job queues out there you can look into: redis pubsub, kafka, celery, etc